# Adding std::shared_ptr to a map ruins programs behaviour

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I'm sorry that I was not able to think of a better title for my question. I've encountered the following problem:

I have a GameObject class, representing everything possible in the world. It can hold several components defining its behaviour. A GameObject is made renderable as following:

```
    //GameObjectPtr is std::shared_ptr<GameObject>
    GameObjectPtr skyBoxGameObject = GameObject::makeGameObject();
    skyBoxGameObject->AddComponent<RenderComponent>(skyBox);
```

In the main Loop, if I now take the RenderComponent from the GameObject as follows:

```
    planeGameObject->GetComponent<RenderComponent>()->Draw();
    skyBoxGameObject->GetComponent<RenderComponent>()->Draw();
```

Everything works fine. On the other hand I now want to implement a RenderSystem which stores the GameObjects by ID and hold a reference to them using, again, std::shared_ptr:

```
    //In RenderSystem:
    std::map<unsigned int, std::shared_ptr<GameObject>> m_gameObjects;
```

Adding a GameObject to the RenderingSystem is done with:

```
    void RenderSystem::AddGameObject(std::shared_ptr<GameObject> gameObjectPtr)
    {
      if (m_gameObjects.count(gameObjectPtr->GetId()) > 0)
        throw std::runtime_error("GameObject already registered");
      if (gameObjectPtr->GetComponent<RenderComponent>() == nullptr)
        throw std::runtime_error("GameObject doesn't provide rendercomponent");
      m_gameObjects[gameObjectPtr->GetId()] = gameObjectPtr;
    }
```

And the drawing is done in this way:

```
   void RenderSystem::DrawAll() const
   {
     for (auto const & gameObject : m_gameObjects)
     {
       gameObject.second->GetComponent<RenderComponent>()->Draw();
     }
   }
```

Unfortunately the Objects are not displayed properly. Is there anything wrong with my code or is something copied/moved by adding it to the map that shouldn't be? I've got no clue.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You will have to describe the actual issue more clearly.

Comment: Oh thats embarassing... Of course, its the ordering. I'm trying to draw something without using the appropriate shader program. Whoever commented about this (and deleted it?) thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I deleted that comment after seeing that it was a `map` and thought you would have already checked that  ;). You are welcome.

Comment: Can one of you restore the solution as an answer? Otherwise the thread isn't useful.

Comment: @Arunmu Please restore the answer for preventing this question from being useless (& closed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at this code:

```
void RenderSystem::DrawAll() const
   {
     for (auto const & gameObject : m_gameObjects)
     {
       gameObject.second->GetComponent<RenderComponent>()->Draw();
     }
   }
```

The `Draw` function gets called in the order of `gameObject` stored in the map `m_gameObjects`, not in the order that you actually need.

A `vector` or `deque` seems to be better alternative to store the objects but in the order in which you want to draw.

Comment: How would you know in which order the objects are needed? From OP it appears that the order is arbitrary.